# I am trying to run python on cmd but i am getting this error '''' 'py' is not recognised as an internal or external command,operable or batch file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to run python on cmd but I am getting this error:

```
'py' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable or batch file.
```

Can anyone help me? See the image below:

[image]

Comment: Try 'python' instead of 'py'

Comment: You need to add the `py` executable to your PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

you should try pip install blah blah blah  rather than py.
if you really want to run python , should  use python instead of py

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try
`pip install pyperclip` or `python -m pip install pyperclip`